# What is the net effect of organized crime on the economy of Italy?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, italy

In connection to this [question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56637/how-is-italy-so-rich-given-its-high-corruption-and-crime/56639#56639) are there any empirical estimates of the effect of organized crime on economy of Italy? I am looking for some net effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is an extensive literature about the relationships between organized crime and economic activity in Italy.**

I’m not sure to understand what you precisely refer to when you say

> I'm looking for some *net effect*

because the impact of organized crime can be analyzed in several respects, from a  regional and territorial  point of view, or by sector of economic activity, or for its impact on the distribution of income, or on investment, or from a microeconomic point of view, and so on.

But I suppose that you are referring first of all to **a macroeconomic point of view,** that is the impact of organized crime **on the level of PIL and on economic growth**.

**It must be said that there aren’t  conclusive  statements  about this impact,** because of  many difficulties linked also to the lack of reliable data.

$\;$

The first source to look at when investigating an aspect of Italy's economy is, of course, the publications by the **Banca d'Italia** (the Italian Central Bank) and its research center, which is the most authoritative non-academic research center in Italy.$^1$

**A recent paper by Banca d’Italia** deals with the impact of organized crime on economy:

[Mocetti S., Rizzica L., *La criminalità organizzata in Italia: un'analisi economica* (Organized Crime in Italy: an Economic Analysis), Questioni di economia e finanza, Banca d’Italia, 2021](https://www.bancaditalia.it/pubblicazioni/qef/2021-0661/QEF_661_21.pdf)

The abstract:

> Organized crime affects the social and economic development of the
> territories where it is rooted through several channels. Therefore,
> it is difficult to analyze these effects, also because of the
> impossibility to observe and measure for certain the presence of
> Mafia. […] this paper (i) analyzes the territorial diffusion of
> organized crime in Italy; (ii) describes the contexts that  could have
> favored the origin and diffusion of mafias beyond traditional
> boundaries; (iii) examines the impact on economic growth and the
> different channels through which these effects occur .(*my
> translation*).

**A recent study has been made by Cgia Mestre** ((Italian Association of Artisans and Small Companies):

The picture that emerges from this study by [Cgia di Mestre](https://www.cgiamestre.com/la-mafia-spa-fattura-40-miliardi-lanno/) 
estimates  at 40 billions of euros  the volume of transactions of organized crime – that is 2% Italian  PIL.

$$\qquad$$

**Below a recent book about the impact of criminality on economic activity:**

[Patalano R., Capitalismo criminale. Analisi economica del crimine organizzato, Giappicchelli,  2020](https://www.giappichelli.it/media/catalog/product/excerpt/9788892134683.pdf)$^2$

$$\;$$

In the previous papers and book  you can find a vast bibliography  from both a theoretical and empirical point of view about the overall effects of organized crime on economic activity.

$$***$$

**For  more specific or sectorial impacts of organized crime,** there are many aspects that have been analyzed:

**An overview can be found in the introduction to a special number of the journal [Moneta e Credito about economy and criminality  in Italy (December 2018)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330934046_Economia_e_criminalita_in_Italia_Un%27introduzione)**

From the abstract :

> The study of criminal behavior from the point of view of economics is
> mostly brought back to the canon of rationality. In this introduction
> to the special issue on crime and economy, we explain why it can be
> appropriate to move away from the extremely widespread vision that
> leads criminal actions to the microeconomic approach and, in
> particular, to the logic of business choices, to assume the point of
> view of those who choose to study crime as a governance structure. In
> particular, it is important to recognize that the activities of
> criminal organizations which have the main economic and political
> repercussions always take on an international dimension. This is an
> extremely important issue for economic policy in Europe.

Abot the **impact on productivity**:

Albanese G. e Marinelli G. (2013), “Organized Crime and Productivity: Evidence from Firm-Level Data”, Rivista
italiana degli economisti, 18 (3), pp. 367-394.

About the **impact on environment**:

Pergolizzi A. (2018), “L’economia avvelenata del crimine ambientale”, Moneta e Credito, 71 (284), pp. 337-353. $^3$

The following  is an article on lavoce.info, a well-known online economic journal, about the infiltration of the mafia in the sector of wind energy, after the Green Deal:

[*Sugli incentivi all’eolico il vento dell’infiltrazione mafiosa*](https://lavoce.info/archives/89363/sugli-incentivi-alleolico-il-vento-delle-infiltrazioni-mafiose/)$^4$

About the **impact on income distribution**:

Clementi F. e Valentini E. (2018), “Economia irregolare, criminalità e diseguaglianza dei redditi: un circolo vizioso?”,
Moneta e Credito, 71 (284), pp. 283-296.$^5$

About **the impact on foreign investments**:

[Daniele V. e Marani U. (2011), *Organized Crime, the Quality of Local Institutions and FDI in Italy: A Panel Data
Analysis*, European Journal of Political Economy, 27 (1), pp. 132-142.](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/eeepoleco/v_3a27_3ay_3a2011_3ai_3a1_3ap_3a132-142.htm)

Abstract:

> This paper examines the impact of crime on foreign direct investment
> (FDI) inflows in the Italian provinces. The incidence of organized
> crime is measured by the number of complaints regarding criminal
> offences of different kinds traditionally related to the mafia
> organizations. The results show how the correlation between organized
> crime and FDI is both negative and significant, even when an indicator
> of financial incentives for investment is included in the regressions.
> Our analysis shows that crime represents a deterrent for foreign
> investors, suggesting that high levels of (certain) crimes may be
> perceived as a signal of a local socio-institutional environment
> unfavorable for FDI.

$\;$

Other information and data can be found in this [**recent article on Sole24ore**](https://www.econopoly.ilsole24ore.com/2018/06/22/mafia-impresa-criminalita/), the most important Italian economic newspaper, which is a reliable source to be consulted when inquiring about Italian economy.

---

$^1$  <sup>Forgive me if I say some obvious things, but I write also for possible readers who don't know Italy's institutions  and Italian economy.</sup>

$^2$ <sup>*Criminal Capitalism: an Economic Analysis of Organized Crime*.</sup>

$^3$ <sup>*The  Poisoned Economy of Environmental Crime.*</sup>

$^4$ <sup>*The wind of Mafia Infiltration over the Incentives for Wind Power.*</sup>

$^5$   <sup>*Illegal Economy, criminality and income inequality: a Vicious Circle?*</sup>